# FileStream is not marked as serializable, but the whole class is?

Tags: c#, serializable

I have a class definition in separate assembly. The class is marked as serializable:

```
namespace example
{
    [Serializable]
    public class my_class
    {
        public List<string> text;
        public FileStream audio;

        public Image img;
        public string nickname;
    }
}
```

I can load this assembly and create an instance of this class with no problem. But when i try to cast to byte[] using code bellow

```
private byte[] ToByteArray()
{
    if (send == null) // 'send' is a my_class instance;
        return null;

    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Binder = new Binder();
    bf.AssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full;
    bf.Binder.BindToType(example_assembly.FullName, "my_class");
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    bf.Serialize(ms, send);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

i get:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException -> Type System.IO.FileStream in Assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.

I don't understand this because whole class is marked as serializable. Any sugestions ??

Comment: Yes, *your* class is marked as serializable, but are each of the *members* also serializable? (IE: `FileStream`)

Comment: As a side note: I really don't recommend BinaryFormatter - I've seen too many people get bitten hard (usually when versioning)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Serializable` attribute simply indicates a class can be serialized. It does not change the underlying functionality of a class. You can mark non-serializable classes and members as serializable.

A `FileStream` is not serializable. Marking it as such will not change that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also, consider using `using` blocks around your `streams`. You want to insure they get cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

Members are serializable, but their types should also be serializable. FileStream is not. You can implement ISerializable interface in your class and manully serialize audio/img fields.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `my_class` is decorated with the `[SerializableAttribute]`, but the class [FileStream](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/IO/FileStream@cs/2/FileStream@cs) is not. =/

You can skip the property serialization by decorating the FileStream property with a `[NonSerializedAttribute]`, but you can't serialize a file Stream.

This is not very beautiful, but this guy [here](http://www.csharp411.com/c-convert-string-to-stream-and-stream-to-string/) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/bd5d4987-d0a8-4db1-a293-9b178ee3c19c/how-to-convert-filestream-to-string) converted the stream to a string. You could control the serialization of your class by implementing the [ISerializale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface and parse the FileStream to something that is Serializable.